# Playing video continously from a directory in a loop

Tags: android, video

i want to play video from external storage directory,all files are in mp4 format i played it in a video view but the problem is that when i use onComplitonlistner next video lost its view only audio came but no video until i touch the display any solution.

```
    final File s[] = videofiles.listFiles();
    mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
            if (s[j].getName().split("[.]")[1].equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")) {
                mylist.add(s[j].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mVideoView.setVideoPath(mylist.get(i));

    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.buildLayer();
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            if (i >= s.length - 1) {
                i = -1;
            }

            linearLayout.refreshDrawableState();

            linear.refreshDrawableState();

            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            mVideoView.refreshDrawableState();
            mVideoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mVideoView.setDrawingCacheQuality(TRIM_MEMORY_BACKGROUND);

            mVideoView.setVideoPath(mylist.get(++i));
            mVideoView.start();

        }
```

logcat is here which is saying media player is not playing the video but auido coming
[image: log cat which is showing that video is no playing but audio is coming continuously]

Comment: using ics 4.0.3 no problem in 2.2 and 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

You might need to request focus again. I have run into some odd issues with focus and video's including differences in behavior from 3.1 to 3.2.

Comment: i have added mvideoview.requestfocus(); on complitionListner but nt working :(